# Reinitialize BorderPane to Scene on outside clicked Node

Tags: javafx-2

I am trying to redesign the right area of a BorderPane ( with a new Pane ) after clicking on a Node situated in the center area of the BorderPane!

I am sure that this is an easy thing to solve, but, till now, I haven't been able to put together information from other resources in relation to my specific issue.

Also, I would prefer the answer to only cover javafx coding solution, since I have not used fxml approach so far!

Your help will be much appreciated!

My code is as following:

click action (in separate class):

```
// StackPane action when clicked
dbShapeStackPane.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
     @Override public void handle(MouseEvent event) {

           //some other actions when clicked  

           //get logic for re-populate pane                        
           DataRAB_SectionReportPane reportListPane = new DataRAB_SectionReportPane();
           Pane reportList = reportListPane.addMainPane(false, reportDisplayName);   

           //activate main class
           BaseGUI mainTab = new BaseGUI();
           mainTab.addReportPane(reportList);               
    }
});
```

main class that contains separate method invoked by above click action:

```
@Override
public void start (Stage primaryStage) {
        //attempt SQL PROMOTEX DB connection
        connection = new AddConnection();
        connection.makeConnection(); 

        innerPane = new BorderPane();   
        DataRAB_SectionReportPane dataRAB_reportPane = new DataRAB_SectionReportPane();
        reportList = new Pane();
        reportList = dataRAB_reportPane.addMainPane(true, "test Label!");
        reportList.setPrefSize(350, 200);

    DataRAB_SectionMenu dataRAB_Menu = new DataRAB_SectionMenu();
    pageMenu = dataRAB_Menu.addHBoxMenu(15,12,15,12);

    DataRAB_SectionValidateDataImportFiles validateData = new DataRAB_SectionValidateDataImportFiles();
    validateDataImport = validateData.buildValidationBorderPane();

    DataRAB_SectionDBsGrid dbGrid = new DataRAB_SectionDBsGrid();
    mainPageGridArea = dbGrid.buildDBGraphicalGrid();

    DataRAB_SectionInfoPane infoGrid = new DataRAB_SectionInfoPane();
    mainPageInfoGridArea = infoGrid.buildInfoGridPane();
    mainPageInfoGridArea.setPrefSize(200, 200);

    innerPane.setCenter(mainPageGridArea);
    innerPane.setTop(pageMenu);
    innerPane.setBottom(validateDataImport);
    innerPane.setRight(reportList);
    innerPane.setLeft(mainPageInfoGridArea);

    Region region = new Region();
    region.getStyleClass().add("stage-init");

    pageMenu.getChildren().add(region);
    primaryStage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);

    final BorderPane mainPane = new BorderPane();   
    final TabPane mainTabPane = new TabPane();

    final Tab data_RABTab = new Tab();
        data_RABTab.setText("Data Validation");
        mainTabPane.setTabClosingPolicy(TabPane.TabClosingPolicy.UNAVAILABLE);
        data_RABTab.setContent(innerPane);
        mainTabPane.getTabs().add(data_RABTab);

    final Main_ToolBar1 mainToolBar = new Main_ToolBar1();
        appMainToolBar = new ToolBar();
        appMainToolBar = mainToolBar.createMainToolBar(primaryStage, mainPageGridArea);
        appMainToolBar.setId("mainToolBar");
        mainPane.setCenter(mainTabPane);
        mainPane.setTop(appMainToolBar);

        scene = new Scene(mainPane, 1200, 700);
        scene.getStylesheets().add(BaseGUI.class.getResource("DataRAB_Styles.css").toExternalForm());     

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show(); 
    }  

//re-add modified Pane to scene    

public void addReportPane(Pane pane){
    pane = new Pane();
    try {
          // innerPane = BorderPane original parent
          innerPane.getChildren().remove(innerPane.getRight());
          innerPane.setRight(pane);
    } catch(Exception ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(BaseGUI.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE,null,ex);
            System.out.println("Right part of Pane NOT removed!");
        }
}    

public static void main(String[] args) { launch(args); }

}
```

Attempting to summarize:

- innerPane ( = the Parent BorderPane container -> defined in the main
  class: Base_GUI)
- dbShapeGrid ( = GridPane; placed on center of innerPane; contains
  StackPane dbShapeStackPane as child; all definition, logic, children 
  of dbShapeGrid exists in its own class)
- my goal here: when dbShapeStackPane is clicked, the right side of innerPane should be re-initialised on scene according to logic in
  method: addMainPane;
  I've tried a different approach as follows (still no success):

```
dbShapeStackPane.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
     @Override public void handle(MouseEvent event) {                    
     //some other actions when clicked                               
     //get logic for re-populate pane ( from class: DataRAB_SectionReportPane)
     //logic is tested and works well if initialised first on scene                       
         DataRAB_SectionReportPane reportListPane = new DataRAB_SectionReportPane();
         Pane reportList = reportListPane.addMainPane(false, reportDisplayName);   
         //activate main class
         BaseGUI mainTab = new BaseGUI(); 
         final BorderPane bp = mainTab.getInnerPane();                        
         //try to re design the innerPane by using runnable
            Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {               
                   bp.setRight(reportList);
                }
            });               
         }
    });
```

...

```
    //replaced old method addReportPane ( in main class: BaseGUI) with the  following:
    public BorderPane getInnerPane (){
        return innerPane;
    }
```

Comment: Are you intentionally assigning new pane as, pane = new Pane(); in the method addReportPane()? And would you mind if I ask you to ask a concrete question, like what you expect from your code, but what is resulting instead of?

Comment: Hi Uluk! Thank you very much for your reply! The idea is to force the original innerPane to re-initialize having the new pane set on the right! pane = new Pane() represents an attempt made for invoking addReportPane() from within the click event, where reportList is also passed and should be the new pane to be re-initialized! I got a hint somewhere that I must use runnables to achieve what I aim for, but again, I might be wrong!

Comment: As per what is resulting from my code, the answer is: nothing! The initial scene remains the same, the new pane (Pane reportList), passed through addReportPane(reportList) to the main class, does not replace the old pane!

Answer (score 0):

The method addReportPane() always setting the right side of the innerPane to the empty pane, instead try as:

```
public void addReportPane(Pane pane) {
    try {
        innerPane.setRight(pane);
    } catch(Exception ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(BaseGUI.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE,null,ex);
        System.out.println("Right part of Pane NOT removed!");
    }
}
```

Also the DB data retrievals should be done in other thread (the runnable you have mentioned) than the JavaFX Main thread. Moreover, the JavaFX also offers its own functionality API for it. Search this site for that topic (like "background job thread, db connection freezing" etc.), there are good reference discussions and demo codes about it.

Comment: Hi! Point well taken! my previous "answer" was moved as edit within the original question! Thank you!